# Net Use command with relative target path

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, subst, net-use

I have a batch file located in several folders and in this file I need to replace the old `subst T: .` command for `net use` because the units (drives) have different properties in windows 7.

However, I have only found that `net use` only allows for absolute paths such as:

```
net use T: \\path\to\folder
```

I cannot work with absolute paths, but `net use T: .` is not allowed (it throws an error).

Is there a way to execute the `net use` command from a folder so that it uses the current .bat directory?

I think the best solution for me it would be to be able to get the absolute qualified path (\path\to\folder) with a batch command. (%cd% and chdir variables do not work in this case). Questions about getting the current directory or folder name are not useful since the `net use`command does not allow paths such as `x:\path\to\folder`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Create a 1:1 replacement for `subst`? Also, I don’t really understand why `subst` isn’t sufficient anymore. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: Of course. I did not go into details because it was not within the scope of the question. When running not-signed executables from a network-drive created with `subst` windows always prompts the message: "publisher could not be verified...", and I need the message not to be displayed.

Comment: @DanielB. Continuation:
The thing is that I have lowered all local network security and tried it all to avoid this message but it keeps popping whenever I run it. However, if the network-drive is created from the `computer --> map network drive` button, even if the related folder path is the same it behaved differently from `subst`. Windows does not show me the message any more this way. So what I need is a windows command to do what that button does.

Answer (score 2):

The `%~dp0` will give exactly what you're asking for (i.e. `\\server\share\to\folder`) . But you **can't** use it for your `net use` command. The `net use` command only accepts the `\\server\share` part to create a drive-letter.

You can do some work to strip off the `\to\folder`-part and add it later in your batch-files but it might be better to use the `pushd \\server\share\to\folder` command. With that command there is a temporary driver-letter created and the current directory is automatically changed to the correct folder. With the `popd`-command you're back where you started and the temporary drive is released.

So:

```
C:\>

C:\>pushd \\wdmycloud\public\new folder

Z:\New folder>::do your thing
Z:\New folder>
Z:\New folder>popd

C:\>
```

B.T.W. if you need to find out what temporary drive is created you can use the `%~d0` in your batch-files. And `%~dp0` for the complete path, and so on (or `%cd%` of course :)).

Comment: I have tried it and it does not work. A command like this: `net use T: c:\path\to\folder` does not work. Net use expects UNC paths such as \\server\path

Comment: @Jorge The ~dp0 should give you a fully qualified UNC-path if you put the batch-file on the network and start it via the UNC path. It doesn't work if you start it from a drive letter already. What do you get with the echo-example?

Comment: @Jorge O wait. This might give you trouble with subfolders. `~dp0` will give you the complete subfolder-path which you can't use for `net use`. You would need to strip those. But wouldn't `pushd` be a better option or do you need it to be `T:` specifically. If you do `pushd \\path\to\folder` you end up in `Z:\folder` with `Z:` being a temporary drive-letter. With `popd` you go back and `Z:` is released. Isn't that a better option ?? (Otherwise I'll try to find a way to strip the folder for you)

Comment: @Jorge Seeing as that you can't use `\\server\share\to\folder` for `net use`-command you can't use `%~dp0` either. I changed my answer completely to using `pushd` which would be much more suitable in this situation.

Comment: Ok, I dont know if I am missing something, but this is what is happening to me: 
I already have \\server\general\path mapped to X:\ (all at work have it this way). What I need now is a subfolder of X: to be mapped to T:.
So: `\\server\general\path\specific\path --> T:`. 
But, when I open a command window from \\server\general\path and I execute a bat file with `echo ~dp0` it gives me X:\specific\path, so `~dp0` is not working for me.

Comment: What we use to have was this command: `subst T: .`(with the dot meaning the current folder). 
By the way, anytime I open a command window from a network drive subfoler windows creates a new drive letter! I dont know why this is happening. Is it related to those temporary drive-letters?

Comment: @Jorge If you're on a drive-letter in a command-prompt and you go to a directory `X:`, `cd folder` and you do `subst T: .` when you go to `T:` you'll be in `X:\folder`. So the command `subst T: .` works just fine for me. That opening a folder directory on a network drive you get a temporary driveletter is normal. The cmd.exe detects that you don't have a letter so assigns one temporarily. This only happens with a command prompt. Not with a batch-file. With a batch-file you need to issue a `pushd %~dp0` first to get that temporary drive-letter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34530/discussion-between-jorge-and-rik).

Comment: But although `subst` creates a new drive letter with the path it has a different behaviour as commented in the original post

Comment: The `%~dp0` **ONLY** gives a qualified UNC-path if you're really run it FROM a UNC-path. If you run it from a driveletter then you also get a drive-letter. But if you run it from a drive-letter you don't need `%~dp0` because you can use relative path with subst. So if you HAVE a driveletter you can just use `subst T: .` and if you DON'T have a driveletter you need to use `pushd %~dp0` to get a letter, after which you could use the `subst T: .`-method.